# Stop some processes from autorunning

Tags: virtualbox, services, tor, tomcat, autorun

As the title, I'm trying to figure out a way to avoid the following processes from autorunning when the system starts: `Virtualbox`, `Tomcat7`, `ntopng`, `tor`.

So, until now, I tried to simply create a `.override` file inside the `/etc/init/` with the `manual` stanza. However, the solution hasn't work until now. I also tried to move these files inside the `/etc/init.d/`, with no success.

However, the same solution used with other files have produced the right behavior. So, what am I supposed to do?

I'm on an `Ubuntu 14.04 x64` machine

### Update 1

As for comments under @Raphael answer.

```
$>ls -l /etc/init.d/tomcat7 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7894 feb 21  2014 /etc/init.d/tomcat7
$>ls -l /etc/init/tomcat7.override 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7 giu  7  2015 /etc/init/tomcat7.override
$>cat /etc/init/tomcat7.override 
manual
```

Answer (score 1):

To show the hidden start-up applications, do:

```
sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
```

Then launch `Startup Applications` from dash.

But if you are still not satisfied, then:

**Be absolutely careful with the below software. Its a very advanced tool**

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bum
```

Now, you will be able to stop most of the processes by launching `BootUp-Manager` from dash.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Why the command line way doesn't work?

Comment: Please post the content of the file so that I may comment

Comment: Which of the files do you refer to?

Comment: `.override` Also this is a guess but the reason those services are not overridden is because the service nanes are not typed ib correctly. Please double check those and then try again. You shall get the name of the VirtualBox services fron `bum` You may uninstall it later

Comment: No problem, I'd already installed `bum` some time ago, even if I've not used it quit often. Btw, I updated my question just a few moments ago.

Comment: @tigerjack89 - So, are the service names correct?

Comment: yes, they are all correct.